# Comando unlink não está funcionando se ativado via include

Tags: php

Estou usando um arquivo no diretório principal do site, com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$diretorioFuncoes = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/buscar"; // Dir dos arquivos
$arrayExcecoes = array(); // * Coloque aqui os arquivos que você quer que não sejam incluidos

if ($handle = opendir($diretorioFuncoes))
{
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if(strpos($file,".php")) // * Só inclui arquivos PHP
        {
            if(!in_array($file,$arrayExcecoes))
            {
                include($diretorioFuncoes."/".$filesize);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Este código acima, faz o "include" de todos arquivos com extensões `.php` dentro do diretório "busca". E está funcionando perfeitamente.

Dentro do diretório "busca", tenho vários arquivos com um código que executa uma consulta sql dentro do banco de dados. Até aqui tudo certo. Eu gostaria que após o comando ser executado, o arquivo se auto excluísse, e estou tentando desta forma:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    if (new DateTime() > new DateTime("2015-04-17")) {
    # current time is greater than 2010-05-15 (Ano - Mês - Dia)

    $sql = "UPDATE `url` SET `type` = 'splash' WHERE `url`.`custom` = '$custom'; ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    unlink ("$custom.php");
    echo ("$custom")," atualizado com sucesso<br><br>";
    } else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

}
else {
echo ("$custom")," - ainda não está na hora.<br>";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Para que o arquivo seja excluído automaticamente, estou adicionando está linha:

```
unlink ("$custom.php");
```

Porém quando este arquivo é executado através do include, o comando unlink me retorna este erro:

> Warning: unlink(meiamaratonasantoandre2016.php) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /public_html/buscar/meiamaratonasantoandre2016.php on line 21

Uma observação importante, é que se eu abrir o arquivo diretamente pelo navegador, e não pelo include, o comando unlink funciona perfeitamente.

Alguém sabe o que posso estar fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso queira que o arquivo auto exclua-se, pode fazer assim

```
unlink(__FILE__);
```

A constante `__FILE__` retorna o path absoluto do arquivo corrente.

Todavia há fatores que podem afetar o funcionamento do que deseja, como exemplo, níveis de acesso e permissão nos arquivos e diretórios.

Caso as permissões estejam devidamente configuradas, não deve apresentar problema.

Num outro caso um pouco mais distante de ser o cenário que possui, é o arquivo em questão estar bloqueado para edição ou remoção por algum outro processo de prioridade elevada.

nota:

```html
Observando o código que postou há diversas coisas estranhas.

De onde vem a variável `$custom`?

unlink ("$custom.php"); // vem de onde?
echo ("$custom")," atualizado com sucesso<br><br>"; // aqui vemos que está bem bagunçado.

Um pouco mais acima temos a query sql:

$sql = "UPDATE `url` SET `type` = 'splash' WHERE `url`.`custom` = '$custom'; ";

Parece que `$custom`, de onde quer que venha, parece que é um URL.

Talvez esteja tentando excluir uma URL, o que não é possível dessa forma pois URLs são caminhos virtuais.

São apenas suposições superficiais baseadas no que postou.

Sem mais delongas, acredito que a sugestão usando `__FILE__` deve resolver.
```

Comment: Olá Daniel,

Com a dica acima deu certo também, mas eu acabei percebendo o problema no código original.

Acontece que eu estava rodando o arquivo através do include em um arquivo de outro diretório, por isso o erro mencionado.

Comment: Por isso a recomendação no uso de caminho absoluto. Pois independente do diretório onde for executado, o caminho será sempre encontrado.

Answer (score 0):

Precisa declarar o caminho absoluto do diretório.

```
$delete = "foo/bar/$custom";
unlink($delete);
```